# Gait-Based Gender Classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm new in this forum and I'm completely new to the neural networks world.
I'm trying to develop a project for my University, and it basically consists of creating a neural network able to classify a person's gender by the way of how he/she walks. They gave me a certain number of .csv files, each one is referred to a specific person, which contain 18 pose landmarks where each of them is composed by three values: x, y, and a probability p that a certain point is in [x, y]. Each tuple of each data set identifies a frame of the video where these data has been extracted.
My question is, is it possible to classify a person's gender by how he/she is walking throughout this data?
I am asking that because I can obtain barely 50% of accuracy, which is not enough for such as purpose. What I did is to build a new data frame where each feature is the distance of a point from a frame to the next one, and I did it for each landmark.
Not sure it is the best way to do that, but I'm not even sure that it's possible to reach this goal by exploiting this data.
That's why I'm asking help to you.

This is the model that I've used:

```
model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(29, ), init='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, init='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(layers.Dense(32, init='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, init='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, init='normal', activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you could share the model's architecture.

Comment: I've updated the topic. Check it out.

Comment: One important detail, Stack Overflow is not a forum and these are not topics. Stack Overflow is a Question & Answer site, and you made a Question. Please take the tour to get information how this site works: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: And now to your actual question, you should not use softmax with one neuron, use sigmoid activation with one neuron for binary classification. Also using so many sigmoid activations in the hidden layers will bring vanishing gradient problems, prefer to use relu (except in the last layer).

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going to read the information you gave to me. Anyway, I have changed my model and it helped a lot, now I can reach almost 90% accuracy. I have one more question, where I can find information about all these parameters? And neural networks in general?